# CodePlex Archive will be shut down after July 1st, 2021

Tags: support, status-completed

Just as the title says, the [CodePlex Archive](https://archive.codeplex.com/) homepage shows:

> #### CodePlex Archive will be shut down after July 1st, 2021.
>
> [...] We now encourage customers to use Github for their open source project hosting needs.
>
> CodePlex will continue as an archive until next July (2021), at which point it will be shut down. [...]

While Android Enthusiasts is not a site that uses CodePlex extensively, still, [there are posts with CodePlex links](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Acodeplex).

Some projects have been migrated to GitHub or another site. Look out for the banner or otherwise the archived body.

> [image]

These are the currently recommended actions:

- For projects that have been migrated, we encourage the community to fix the links by (suggest an) edit.
- For projects that have *not* been migrated:

  1. You may try searching for the project name in your favorite search engine and see if there is a mirrored/forked repository; then you may replace the link with it.
  2. If there doesn't seem any mirror but the post can still be salvaged, try removing the problematic part while leaving the rest of the post valid.
  3. You may also notify the OP about this issue and provide some suggestions like migrating the repo to GitHub or another site, providing the mirrors for the executables, or anything else that might help them fix the issue.
  4. If it links to a specific page on the archive, you may try using [Internet Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) to find the archive of the archive.
  5. Otherwise, if the posts cannot be salvaged without the link, feel free to flag/vote to close them.

Comment: It says "next July (2021)".  Was this notice published in 2020?

Comment: @RayButterworth [earliest notice was on January 27, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127000031/https://archive.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I was unaware that their archive was closing until I read your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All posts have been taken action.**

Here is the list of non-deleted posts (previously) pointing to https://archive.codeplex.com for historical/audit purpose:

**Droid Explorer (migrated to [GitHub](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer))**

- [Control an Android phone remotely from the computer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104290/control-an-android-phone-remotely-from-the-computer/104379#104379) (migrated)
- [Documentation for Droid Explorer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128367/documentation-for-droid-explorer/128368#128368) (migrated)
- [Unable to locate SDK when starting Droid Explorer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95527/unable-to-locate-sdk-when-starting-droid-explorer) (migrated)
- [How can I explore my Android from my computer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15095/how-can-i-explore-my-android-from-my-computer/15106#15106) (migrated)
- [How do I export & import files between Android devices and Windows OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12508/how-do-i-export-import-files-between-android-devices-and-windows-os/12547#12547) (migrated)
- [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25646/how-do-i-backup-data-sms-contacts-from-a-device-with-a-broken-screen/25671#25671) (migrated)
- [Droid Explorer app does not show hidden files](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132900/droid-explorer-does-now-show-hidden-files/132908#132908) (migrated)
- [Transfer SMS message history, without Google account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86349/transfer-sms-message-history-without-google-account/86367#86367) (migrated)
- ["/sdcard/Sounds" folder appears empty in Windows 7 for Samsung Galaxy S3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69121/galaxy-s3-sdcard-sounds-folder-appears-empty-in-windows-7/71366#71366) (migrated)
- [Where are TWRP backups stored on SD card? Had to un-root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57842/where-are-twrp-backups-stored-on-sd-card-had-to-un-root/143200#143200) (migrated)
- [Why can't I access /data/data with Droid Explorer on my rooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145493/why-cant-i-access-data-data-with-droidexplorer-on-my-rooted-phone) (migrated)
- [How can I search the SMSs/MMSs using the default search interface?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39422/how-can-i-search-the-smss-mmss-using-the-default-search-interface/39426#39426) (migrated)
- [Transfer files from Nexus 5 to PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180191/transfer-files-from-nexus-5-to-pc/180214#180214) (migrated)
- [Galaxy S4's LCD broken. How do I access hidden folders in the storage using computer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97688/galaxy-s4s-lcd-broken-how-do-i-access-hidden-folders-in-the-storage-using-comp/98964#98964) (migrated)
- [Backup using adb on a phone with a dead screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36224/backup-using-adb-on-a-phone-with-a-dead-screen/36253#36253) (migrated)
- [Restore app data from a copied 'com.company.appname' folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68280/restore-app-data-from-a-copied-com-company-appname-folder) (migrated)
- [Mount Android file system on Windows or Linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89501/windows-mount-android-file-system/89527#89527) (migrated)
- [Droid Explorer - Input string was not in a correct format](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134920/droid-explorer-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format/134947#134947) (archived)
- [Droid Explorer does not recognize my HTC Incredible S](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101396/droid-explorer-does-not-recognize-my-htc-incredible-s/101751#101751) (link removed)
- [Can't see photos when using Droid Explorer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138216/cant-see-photos-when-using-droid-explorer/138363#138363) (link removed)

**Virtual Router (migrated to [GitHub](https://github.com/crpietschmann/VirtualRouter))**

- [Is internet tethering possible on Android phone via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/549/is-internet-tethering-possible-on-android-phone-via-bluetooth-or-wifi/550#550) (migrated)
- [How to make an unrooted phone use or detect ad-hoc Wi-Fi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-make-an-unrooted-phone-use-or-detect-ad-hoc-wi-fi/69382#69382) (migrated)
- [Accessing Tor on Android device via a virtual wifi network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/accessing-tor-on-android-device-via-a-virtual-wifi-network/27497#27497) (link removed)

**Others**

- [What podcast apps include variable speed playback?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-podcast-apps-include-variable-speed-playback/1286#1286) (migrated)
- [Where do I find the minimum requirements for an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34782/where-do-i-find-the-minimum-requirements-for-an-app/34806#34806) (migrated)
- [USB transfer speed ridiculously slow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/usb-transfer-speed-ridiculously-slow/44493#44493) (link removed)

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for all the hard work!